# Complex table over multiple pages in combination with adjustbox

Tags: tables, longtable, threeparttable, adjustbox

**Problem statement**

I am fairly new to tables in Latex and currently really struggling with the `longtable` package. Questions as to how to make tables over multiple pages have already been asked several times on Stackexchanges. However, I can't seem to find a solution to my specific problem:

I have the following table (only the first two rows are shown) in landscape-mode and use `adjustbox`to resize the table to 23cm, and `threeparttable`to add notes to my table:

```
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{lscape} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
%%%%%

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[]
\caption{Study characteristics.}
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=23cm}
\begin{threeparttable}

\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright}p{2.5cm} >{\raggedright}p{0.25\linewidth} >{\raggedright}p{0.2\linewidth} >{\raggedright}p{0.25\linewidth} c c c l}

\toprule
Study                            &      
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Intervention} &      
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Population}   &
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Outcome}      &
k                                & 
n                                & 
\begin{tabular}[c]{c}Effect size \\ measure\end{tabular} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{tabular}[c]{c}Effect size \\ {[}95\% CI{]}\end{tabular}}  \\ 
\midrule

Alford \& Derzon (2012)         &
School-based interventions to reduce violence and antisocial behavior &
School-aged children and youths & 
Physical aggression, antisocial behavior, aggressive/disruptive behavior, and delinquent behavior         & 
41      &       --              &       
g       &       
0.133 {[}0.082, 0.184{]}\tnote{**} \\ \addlinespace[0.2cm]

Anderson \& Whiston (2005)      &
Sexual assault college education programs                             &
College students                &
Incidence of sexual assault perpetration &
--      &       --              &       
d       &
0.101 {[}0.036, 0.167{]}\tnote{*} \\ \addlinespace[0.2cm]

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
{\small
\textit{Note.} My notes. \\
\item[*] $p$ \textless{} 0.05. \item[**] $p$ \textless{} 0.01. 
}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

**Question**

How do I implement `longtable` in this particular case? If I simply replace `\begin{tabular}` with `\begin{longtable}` it starts to mess around with my notes (I only want them to be shown on the last page). I assume I have to get rid of `adjustbox`, but how would I resize the table to 23cm in that case?

*Any help will be much appreciated!*

Comment: Could you please post a compilable code, not just a snippet?

Comment: @Bernard I added a missing package (adjustbox), but apart from that it should be compilable? Or do you need all the row entries?

Comment: adjustbox creates a box and such a box can not be splitted over pages.

Comment: To be compilable, it should begin with `\documentclass`, which you don't mention, load the necessary packages, and end with `\end{document}`. So I've posted a possible solution with a standard document class.

Comment: @Bernard I am sorry... I focused so much on my table that I forgot to include other basic information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyway you shouldn't use `adjustbox` with tables, as it leads to inconsistent font sizes. Here is a solution with `xltabular` package, which brings the functionalities of `longtable` to `tabularx`, hence a control on tha totalwdth of the table I also use the `threeparttablex` package, which brings `threeparttable` to longtables, and adds the possibility of cross-references to table notes. Beware the syntax for table notes is slightly different from the syntax of the original table notes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}%
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{6pt}

\usepackage{booktabs, caption}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
%\keepXColumns
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}[para,flushleft]
\small
\textit{Note.} My notes. \\
\item[*] $p$ \textless{} 0.05. \item[**] $p$ \textless{} 0.01.
\end{TableNotes}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{}*{4}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X} c c c l}
\caption{Study characteristics.} \\
\endfirsthead
\toprule%
Study &
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Intervention} &
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Population} &
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Outcome} &
k &
n &
\makecell{Effect size \\ measure} &
\makecell{Effect size \\ {[}95\% CI]} \\
\midrule
%
Alford \& Derzon (2012) &
School-based interventions to reduce violence and antisocial behavior &
School-aged children and youths &
Physical aggression, antisocial behavior, aggressive/disruptive behavior, and delinquent behavior &
41 & -- &
g &
0.133 {[}0.082, 0.184{]}\tnote{**} \\ \addlinespace[0.2cm]
%
Anderson \& Whiston (2005) &
Sexual assault college education programs &
College students &
Incidence of sexual assault perpetration &
-- & -- &
d &
0.101 {[}0.036, 0.167{]}\tnote{*} \\ \addlinespace[0.2cm]
\bottomrule
\insertTableNotes
\end{xltabular}
\end{ThreePartTable}
\hfill
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a million! It works like a charm.